# Read appsettings.json into object that has an interface defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to read custom settings from appsettings.json into a POCO object that has a custom interface defined.  This code works - but is there a better way to do this?  Maybe something similar to reading the options via services.Configure and IOptions?  Unfortunately, using IOptions is not possible since I am calling another library that expects an object that implements an 'IConfigOptions' interface.

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigOptions>(obj => new ConfigOptions        
{
   Param1 = Configuration["Options:Param1"],
   Param2 = Configuration["Options:Param2"],
   Param3 = Configuration["Options:Param3"],
   <etc>
});
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is methode in `Configuration` in C# which automatically reads all the property for you from the appsettings.

If the properties of the object match with the names in the JSON, then you can do the following:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigOptions,ConfigOptions>(_ =>
              Configuration
                  .GetSection(nameof(ConfigOptions))
                  .Get<ConfigOptions>());
```

The appsettings.json looks like:

```
  "ConfigOptions": {
      "Param1": "text1",
      "Param2": "text2",
      "Param3": "text3"
  }
```

The ConfigOptions looks like this:

```
public class ConfigOptions {
     public string Param1 { get; set; }
     public string Param2 { get; set; }
     public string Param3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had been staring at this for way too long and needed another set of eyes.  I knew I was overlooking a fairly simple answer but was too brain-dead to see it.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

in startup.cs file you should have the Configuration Property on it for example

```
   public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

and after that you can write the following :

```
var modelConfiguration = Configuration
                .GetSection("Section")
                .Get<YourModel>();
            services.AddSingleton(modelConfiguration );
```

"Section" :  representing the the section in app.settings.json file

YourModel : representing the class that's act like a container for the params in the app.settings section

`services.AddSingleton(modelConfiguration )` : to make it accessible using DI

Comment: Thanks...this was close.  The response I marked as 'Answered' tied it to the interface which is what I needed for DI.

Answer (score 0):

sth like that?

```
 var config = new MailConfiguration();
   _configuration.Bind("Outbox.Email", config);
   

  "Outbox.Email": {
    "smtp": "smtp.com",
    "port": 587,
    "user": "user@user.com",
    "from": "user name",
    "password": "669855,",
  },
```